# MySQL Accounts Aging Report

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a query working in MySQL 5.0.81 that will pull the amount due on invoices that havent been paid.

I have three tables that look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `CLMS_invoices` (
  `invoices_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `invoices_client_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `invoices_datetimestamp` varchar(50) collate latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `invoices_description` varchar(100) collate latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `invoices_discount` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `invoices_note` text collate latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `invoices_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`invoices_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE `CLMS_invoices_payments` (
  `invoices_payments_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `invoices_payments_invoice_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `invoices_payments_datetimestamp` varchar(50) collate latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `invoices_payments_type` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `invoices_payments_paid` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`invoices_payments_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE `CLMS_invoices_products` (
  `invoices_products_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `invoices_products_invoice_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `invoices_products_name` varchar(50) collate latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `invoices_products_price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `invoices_products_profit` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `invoices_products_qty` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `invoices_products_shipping` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`invoices_products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

I need the query to do the following:
Pull invoices based on client_id (invoices_client_id) that are not paid (invoices_status = 0).

The aging should be as follows:
Less than 30 days
31 - 60 days
61 - 90 days
Greater than 90 days

It will also need to return the client id associated with the amounts that fall into the aging groups.

The dollar value in the groups should be calculated as follows:
Invoice Product Cost - Invoice Discount - Amount Paid so far

Invoice Product Cost is calculated as

> SUM((invoices_products_price +
>   invoices_products_profit +
>   invoices_products_shipping) *
>   invoices_products_qty) WHERE
>   invoices_products_invoice_id =
>   invoices_id

Invoice Discount is stored in invoices_discount

Amount Paid so far is calculated as

> SUM(invoices_payments_paid) WHERE
>   invoices_payments_invoice_id =
>   invoices_id

The end result should look something like so:

```
client_id pastDue1 pastDue2 pastDue3 pastDue4
1 12.00 0.00 0.00 15.00
5 2.00 60.00 80.00 32.00
etc
```

Can someone help me build this query?

Comment: This column naming style makes me sick.

Comment: I'd love to help! Where should I send my proposal for consulting services?

Comment: @cherouvim: wait till you see a 3 table join with fully qualified field names...

Comment: ...um, yeah. This is a little ridiculous. Clean up the schema and show that you've done some work on your own before asking other people to get your work done for you pro bono.

Comment: You have a fundamental design flaw in that you represent payments as belonging to specific invoices.  What's going to happen the first time a customer sends a single payment covering multiple invoices?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly - the key issue here is separating all the users into different age groups.

this can be accomplished by the `IF(condition, then, else)` statement in MySQL as follows:

put the first query into a temporary table -

```
CREATE TABLE `tmeporary_invoices`
SELECT invoices.`invoices_client_id`,
       SUM((products.`invoices_products_price` + products.`invoices_products_profit` + products.`invoices_products_shipping`) * products.`invoices_products_qty`) AS invoice_product_cost,
       SUM(payments.`invoices_payments_paid`) AS amount_paid_so_far,
       IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), invoices.`invoices_datetimestamp`) <= 30 , 'pastDue1', IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),invoices.`invoices_datetimestamp`) <= 60, 'pastDue2', 'pastDue2' )) AS age
FROM `CLMS_invoices` invoices
     LEFT JOIN `CLMS_invoices_payments` payments
            ON payments.`invoices_payments_invoice_id` = invoices.`invoices_id`
     LEFT JOIN `CLMS_invoices_products` products
            ON products.`invoices_products_invoice_id` = invoices.`invoices_id`
WHERE invoices.`invoices_status = 0
```

afterwards select from the temporary table above as follows -

```
SELECT `invoices_client_id`,
       SUM(`invoice_product_cost`) AS invoice_product_cost,
       SUM(`amount_paid_so_far`) AS amount_paid_so_far,
       SUM(IF(`age` = 'pastDue1',1,0) AS `pastDue1`,
       SUM(IF(`age` = 'pastDue2',1,0) AS `pastDue2`,
       SUM(IF(`age` = 'pastDue3',1,0) AS `pastDue3`,
FROM `tmeporary_invoices`
GROUP BY `invoices_client_id`
```

The queries should be used as a general guideline on how to accomplish the desired results (simply copy/pasting them may cause some errors in naming conventions/syntax since i could not test them at the moment.

Good Luck!